# my database does not Update when I run my code using update or updateOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm currently learning NodeJS and I wrote a code to update my database using mongoose. At first, I thought it was a deprecation issue, I then added the `useFindAndModify: false` parameter in the `mongoose.connect()`. However, for some reason, it still didn't update in my database. [This is the output of my code when I run it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDzZD.png)

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises',{ useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then( () => console.log('Connected to database'))
    .catch( () => console.error('Cannot connect to database'))


const courseSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    author: String,    
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number,
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id) {

        const result = await Course.updateOne({_id: id}, {
            $set: {
                author: 'Mosh', 
                isPublished: false
            }
        });
        console.log(result);

}

updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the right ID of existing course

Comment: Do you have some other files that use mongo except this?

Comment: @Gramotei Yes I am. I copied the ID directly from the database and pasted it in the argument of the `updatedCourse()` function call.

Comment: @Deda I don't have any other file that is currently using mongo except this one I'm having issue with.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of  that course document with _id 5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e in  your courses collection?

Comment: @SuleymanSah [This is the link and the document id is indicated with a red paint](https://res.cloudinary.com/matehc/image/upload/v1590432770/Stackoverflow/database_vkxq9e.png)

Comment: You save _id as string, it must be ObjectId like this: `_id: ObjectId("5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e")`  There is a problem how you save the document. Can you show the code where you create documents?

Comment: I  imported the collection from a [JSON file](https://res.cloudinary.com/matehc/raw/upload/v1590433944/Stackoverflow/exercise-data_ozfxm1.json) using the `mongoimport --db mongo-exercises --collection courses --drop --file exercise-data.json --jsonArray` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_id values seem to be `String` on your courses collection, but they must be `ObjectId` so that the query can work.

Delete the courses collection,  remove the _id keys and values in the json data so that the MongoDB can create the _id correctly with type ObjectId. 
After importing the documents with mongoimport, your update will work as expected.